# Variational form of matrix

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

Sorry for boring you my friends during spring holiday. I am haunted by a question of matrix differentiation.

$\textbf{R}$ is a matrix of dimension $3\times3$. It is parametrized by three variables $a$, $b$ and $c$. I would like to form the variational form of this matrix. My trial is given by

$$\delta \textbf{R} = \frac{\partial \textbf{R}}{\partial a} \delta a + 
\frac{\partial \textbf{R}}{\partial b} \delta b + \frac{\partial \textbf{R}}{\partial c} \delta c$$

I have serious doubt about this expression. Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: The derivative of the matrix-valued function with respect to each variable is the matrix of the derivatives of the entries with respect to the same variable.

Comment: Not sure why you have any doubts, you've simply expanded the differential of a matrix in terms of its scalar parameters.